# In array of objects turn object values into key/value pair

Tags: javascript, chartkick

I am interested to use [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick) and so I need to convert JS object with the following format:

```
var array = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}, {date:'02/01/2017',value1:220,value2:330,value3:430},{date:'03/01/2017',value1:250,value2:330,value3:420}]
```

To the following format:

```
var arrayOne = [{'01/01/2017': 200}, {'02/01/2017': 220},{'03/01/2017':250}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const src = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}, {date:'02/01/2017',value1:220,value2:330,value3:430},{date:'03/01/2017',value1:250,value2:330,value3:420}],

      result = src.map(({date,value1}) => ({[date]: value1}))
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this**

```js
let sampleArray = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}, {date:'02/01/2017',value1:220,value2:330,value3:430},{date:'03/01/2017',value1:250,value2:330,value3:420}]


   let finalArray = sampleArray.map(data => ({[data.date]:data.value1}))

console.log(finalArray)
```

**Output Will be**

```
[{01/01/2017: 200},{02/01/2017: 220},{03/01/2017: 250}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var array = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}, {date:'02/01/2017',value1:220,value2:330,value3:430},{date:'03/01/2017',value1:250,value2:330,value3:420}];
    var mappedArray = array.map(item => {
    return {
        [item.date]: item.value1
    }
})
```

loop the array and map it to the new structure

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
 var array = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}, {date:'02/01/2017',value1:220,value2:330,value3:430},{date:'03/01/2017',value1:250,value2:330,value3:420}]
 
let final_array =  array.map(arr => {
    return {[arr.date] : arr.value1};
 })

console.log(final_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a loop for each value1, value2, ...

```js
var array = [{
  date: '01/01/2017',
  value1: 200,
  value2: 300,
  value3: 400
}, {
  date: '02/01/2017',
  value1: 220,
  value2: 330,
  value3: 430
}, {
  date: '03/01/2017',
  value1: 250,
  value2: 330,
  value3: 420
}]

const numberOfValues = 3;

for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfValues; i++) {
  const mappedArray = array.map(x => {
    const result = {};
    result[x.date] = x["value" + i.toString()];
    return result;
  });
  console.log(mappedArray);
}
```